# C# escape double quotes not working as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, escaping

I'm trying to escape double quotes in a string in C#, but things aren't working as I expected.  My code looks like this:-

```
public JObject GetIndicatorsAsJSON()
{

    String Test = "";

    foreach (var ARow in db.IPMSApp_TestGridView)
    {
        Test += ",{ \"indicator\" : \"" + ARow.indicator + "\", \"type\": \"" + ARow.type + "\\"}";
    }

    Test = "[" + Test.Substring(1, Test.Length - 1) + "]"; //Strip out first comma

    JObject json = JObject.Parse(Test);

    return json;
}
```

When I try to run this I get an error (which I kind of expected), but on checking the contents of the 'Test' variable in the console window I'm finding that, instead of seeing double quotes as expected (because I've escaped them), I'm seeing "\"" instead.

For example - my output for the Test string variable should look something like this (simplified for purposes of question):-

[{ "indicator" : "Activity - First" }]

But instead it looks like this:-

[{ \"indicator\" : \"Activity - First\" }]

Am I doing something wrong in how I'm escaping the double quotes?  I've tried using a verbatim string literal and I still have the same problem.

Comment: No, that is fine, that is just how console will output a string with escaped quotes. What is your JSON error?

Comment: You seem to be wrapping in `[]` which is an array, have you tried `JArray.Parse(Test);` instead?

Comment: Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1.

Comment: I wrapped in [ ] because I thought that was what i should do.  If I remove these I get the following:-
Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: ,. Path '', line 1, position 54.

Comment: JArray.Parse(Test) worked perfectly...if you post as an answer I'll accept.

Comment: Looks like you have a syntax error in the code near ARow.type + "\\"}"; It must be ARow.type + "\"}"; with single slash instead of two. Are you sure your code was compiling?

Comment: Yep, everything now works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with you quote escaping, the console will just output it in that format, but it is fine (albeit confusing).

I expect the problem is with parsing the JSON. As you are wrapping your objects in an array `[]` you should use the following instead:

```
JArray json = JArray.Parse(Test);
```